# Crontab fails to execute a bash script

Tags: cron

I have a crontab job that looks like below

```
49 14 * * *  /home/ec2-user/gitlabbackupscript/backup.sh
```

when i execute the script in standalone it works, but this cron job is not running. This .sh script is a very simple one liner as follows

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
sudo docker exec -it gitlabce_web_1 gitlab-rake gitlab:backup:create STRATEGY=copy CRON=1 > /home/ec2-user/cronjobs/cronjoblog.log
```

i am new to linux world, any help on this would be helpful, i am not sure what am i missing here.

Comment: Does `backup.sh` have execute permissions? Is this the system or the user crontab? If it's the system crontab, you have to add the user for which the script is to be executed.

Comment: yes backup.sh has execute permission and i have tried both the crontab, but same result

Comment: What user should the script run as? If you use the crontab in `/etc/crontab`, the entry has to look like `49 14 * * * username command`.

Comment: Do you see anything in the system logs for cron? Is the cron daemon running?

Comment: Check the [tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/cron/info) for a lot of useful debugging hints.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're not executing the script in bash.

Try this :

```
49 14 * * *  /bin/bash /home/ec2-user/gitlabbackupscript/backup.sh
```